# Is there an analytic function on $\mathbb D$ with $\vert f\vert\leq1$ on $\mathbb D$ and $f(-1/2)=0$ and $f(1/2)=5/6$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove or disprove that there does not exists an analytic function f on $\mathbb D,$ the open unit disk in the complex plane, such that $\vert f\vert\leq1$ on $\mathbb D, f(-1/2) = 0$ and $f(1/2) = 5/6.$

I think this is an application of the Schwarz Lemma, but I fail to see how to bring it in since $f(0)\ne0$. Do I need to use conformal maps in this example?

I also tried using the Schwarz-Pick Theorem, but noticed that is not allowed as the function does not map $\mathbb D$ onto itself. If I could somehow make use of the Schwarz-Pick Theorem, them it would yield the contradiction that $5/6\leq1/2,$ and it would be solved. Is there a way to apply the Theorem here that I am not seeing?

---

Any hints on how to proceed are much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Take an automorphism of the disc that sends $0$ to $-1/2$. For example, $g(z)=\frac{2z+1}{-z-2}$. Then $h=f\circ g$ satisfies $|h(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1$ and $h(0)=0$. By Schwarz's lemma $|h(z)|\leq |z|$ for $|z|\leq 1$. Now $g^{-1}(1/2)=-4/5$. Then $4/5\geq |h(-4/5)|=|f(1/2)|=5/6$.

Comment: Obviously $f$ maps $\mathbb D$ into itself since if $|f(z_0)|=1$ for some $|z_0|<1$, $f$ would be constant by maximum modulus; Schwarz-Pick leads to $\frac{5}{6} < \frac{4}{5}$ and that is incorrect, so no such function